# Collapsing the current outline in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Say I am in org-mode in a document with the following structure:

```
* First headline 
* Second headline
** Section A
   Here is one line
   Here is another line
   blah, blah
** Section B
```

Say the cursor is on the line that reads `Here is another line`. I would like to collapse `** Section A` from this location with a keyboard shortcut.

- If I press `<TAB>` it does not collapse `** Section A`, as I would need the cursor to be on the stars for this to work.
- If I press `<Shift-TAB>` it collapses **all** outlines, and not the current one.

Is there any way to **cycle** through the collapsing of the outline **in scope** (i.e. the "current outline")?

Comment: Once it has collapsed to `** Section A`, would you want that command to expand that headline, or to collapse the next headline up (`Second headline`)?

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Expanding it again would be great!

Comment: In that case @cyon 's answer will do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeech-Pepin. How could I accomplish the alternative? (i.e. collapse the next headline up)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can customize the behaviour of the `org-cycle` command (which is bound to `<TAB>`) by changing the value of `org-cycle-emulate-tab`.

To get it to collapse `** Section A` when your cursor is on `Here is another line` add the following line to your .emacs file:

```
(setq org-cycle-emulate-tab 'white)
```

The `white` will allow you to still use `<TAB>` to indent in empty lines. From [org-mode Github](https://github.com/tkf/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/org.el#L963):

```
org-cycle-emulate-tab's value is t

Documentation:
Where should `org-cycle' emulate TAB.
nil         Never
white       Only in completely white lines
whitestart  Only at the beginning of lines, before the first non-white char
t           Everywhere except in headlines
exc-hl-bol  Everywhere except at the start of a headline
```

Comment: I don't feel this helps. First of all, do we have a command to "collapse the next headline up"? EDIT: Found a solution;) https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41703/fold-the-immediate-outer-section-in-org-mode

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind doing this in two steps:

1. `C-c C-p`: [move the cursor to the previous heading](https://orgmode.org/manual/Motion.html) (`** Section A` in your example)
2. `TAB`: fold the section

This method doesn't require any configuration, as long as you get used to it.